# Not able to compile external precompiled shared library with Android-NDK

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I have two shared library: `A.so` and `B.so` and want to link them with my `Android Project`.

1. Create a new Android Project from Eclipse
2. Right click on project-> Android Tools-> Add Native support
3. It created a new folder: `JNI`, `JNI/projectname.cpp` and `JNI/Android.mk`
4. Now i add `A.so` and  `B.so` to `<Project-folder>/libs/armeabi`

When i build the project i got this output in console:

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project fona ****

/home/users/android-ndk/ndk-build all 
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-19 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
[armeabi] Install        : projectname.so => libs/armeabi/libprojectname.so

 *** Build Finished ****
```

My concern is that it didn't build `A.so` and `B.so` with `Project.so`. May be i am something missing in `Android.mk` file

## Content of `Android.mk` file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := projectname
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := projectname.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: What do you mean, saying "it didn't build A.so and B.so with Project.so"? A.so and B.so are already built, and will be used as-is. Only your projectname.so will build.

Comment: @Ganster41 Got it! But is there any way to find out that they are successfully integrated with the project?

Comment: libs/armeabi folder will be cleared after every build. Look at my answer, how to add prebuilts correctly. If libs integrated correct, it will be copied to libs/armeabi folder after build, and will be present in resulting APK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just place prebuilt libraries. You need to define it as separate modules, too.
Move your A.so and B.so to jni folder, and modify your Android.mk like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := A
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := A.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := B
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := B.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := projectname
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := projectname.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: I got this:
Android NDK: ERROR:jni/Android.mk:A: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file

Comment: Did you moved A.so to jni folder? And if it has different name, you need to change it in this line: LOCAL_SRC_FILES := A.so

Comment: Looks like your A.so isn't correct Android library. It's public? Can you share that so files?

Comment: Sure! 
A.so : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20476478/libFragCatalog.so
B.so : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20476478/libSmilesParse.so

Actually i compiled these library from C++ source code and it generated them with two other library:
i.e. : `libFragCatalog.so.1` and `libFragCatalog.so.1.2014.09.1pre`

Comment: When i put them directly into `armeabi` each of them showing their member functions.

Comment: It compiled with different toolchain. You can't use it in Android. You can try to rebuild it with Android NDK (write own Android.mk, or use NDK as standalone toolchain...). But looks like it depends on glib, which not available in Android.

Comment: How do you find out that it is using glib?

Comment: It visible at symbols table at the bottom of file. I'm not sure, may be it can build with Android bionic, may be not...

Comment: Problem is solved now :)

I added APP_ABI := x86 in Application.mk and got correct output :)